# JavaScript validation for username and password

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The requirements are:

> 1. Check the user to enter a username that begins with a character[a-zA-Z] and Check the user to enter a username that is 3 or more
>    alphanumeric characters.
> 2. require the user to enter a password that is 8 or more characters where at-least 1 uppercase letter And 1 number AND 1 of the special
>    characters (/*-+!@#$^&*).
> 3. AND password and the confirm password input is same.

I have done for the email and required inputs but is confused on how to do this in JavaScript.

This is what i have done:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
        var nameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z\-]+$/;
    var passregex= /^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+*!]).*$/;
    var uname = document.myForm.firstName.value.match(nameRegex);
    var firstpassword=document.myForm.password.value;  
    var secondpassword=document.myForm.password2.value;
        var firstpassword = document.myForm.password.value.match(passregex);
    
    if(uname == null){
        if(uname.length<3){
        alert("Username length should be atleast 3 and make sure it starts with A-Z");}
        return false;
  }
  elseif(firstpassword==null){
    if(firstpassword.length<8){  
      alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");  
      return false;  
    }
    elseif(firstpassword==secondpassword){
      alert("Please enter same password");  
      return false;  
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share your previous attempts?

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-form-validation check here

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you.

Comment: @Parth, sorry! Now i have added it

Comment: If you want to match a regular expression with something, you can't use a direct assignment like this ``name!="^[A-Za-z]"``  You need to match the pattern with the input by the user. So you can use ``if(YourRegularExpression.test(stringThatIsUserInput))``, If it matches it will return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function validateForm() {
  if (document.myForm.userName.value && document.myForm.password.value && document.myForm.confirmpassword.value) {
    if (document.myForm.password.value === document.myForm.confirmpassword.value) {
      if (document.myForm.userName.value.length < 3) {
        alert("Username length should be atleast 3 and make sure it starts with A-Z");
        return false;
      } else if (document.myForm.password.value.length < 8) {
        alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");
        return false;
      } else {
        if (new RegExp(/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]+$/).test(document.myForm.userName.value) === false) {
          alert('Username begins with a character[a-zA-Z] ');
          return false;
        } else if (new RegExp(/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8, 30}$ /).test(document.myForm.password.value)) {
          alert("password is 8 or more characters where at-least 1 uppercase letter And 1 number AND 1 of the special characters (/-+!@#$^&)");
          return false;
        } else {
          alert('Success !');
          return true;
        }
      }
    } else {
      alert("password & confirm password not match!");
      return false;
    }
  } else {
    alert("Please add valid credentials..");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="main.html" method="post">
  <!--  onSubmit="return validateForm();" -->
  <label>User name</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="userName" />
  <br />
  <label>Password</label><br />
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
  <br />
  <label>Confirm Password</label><br />
  <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="confirm password" />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Login" onclick='validateForm();' />
</form>
```

Note:- I have added all your points please let me know incase something went wrong!

Comment: You are Awsome :)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use jQuery Validation(https://jqueryvalidation.org/). It can be easily implemented.

Comment: I don't want to use this.

Comment: This question is not tagged with [tag:jquery]